# Grouping COVID cases by month and year

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to group COVID case numbers into monthly and yearly groupings. Ex Jan 2020 had x amount of cases, Feb 2020 had x amount of cases, March 2020 had x amount of cases and etc,.

I was able to create a column that groups by month and year but I’m not getting correct case count totals. I’m using BigQuery and I’ve tried the following.

```
SELECT
 Continent,
 Location,
 Format_Date( ‘%b-%Y’, date) Mon_Year,
 SUM(new_cases) AS ‘case_count’
FROM
 covid_cases
Where
 Continent = ‘United States’
GROUP BY
 Continent,
 Location,
 Mon_year
```

Dates in the original dataset are formatted ‘01-01-2020’ and are chronological through 2022 for various countries.

Columns are: continent, location, date, new_cases, total_cases, total_deaths, new_deaths.

Comment: _"Dates in the original dataset are formatted ‘01-01-2020'"_ - why aren't you storing dates _correctly_ by storing them in `date`-typed columns?

Comment: Does your query, as-posted, not produce any errors at all? IIRC BigQuery doesn't let you reference column-expressions in the `GROUP BY` clause of queries at the same depth (this is because [`GROUP BY` happens _before_ `SELECT`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/196292/10044) ) - but if you use an outer-query it should work.

Comment: Off-topic, but the United States is not a continent

Answer (score 0):

> Dates in the original dataset are formatted ‘01-01-2020’

Since `date` column is not a DATE type but a string, you can't use *format_date* function directly. cosider to convert it to DATE type first.

> SUM(new_cases) AS ‘case_count’

When you specify a column alias which need to be quoted, use backtick(`) instead of a single quote(') though it's not necessary in this case.

```sql
SELECT
 Continent,
 Location,
 Format_Date('%b-%Y', PARSE_DATE('%d-%m-%Y', date)) Mon_Year,
 SUM(new_cases) AS `case_count`
FROM
 covid_cases
Where
 Continent = 'United States'
GROUP BY
 Continent,
 Location,
 Mon_year
```

ps. for `Mon_Year`, just using RIGHT(date, 7) seems enough to me if it's format is `%d-%m-%Y`.